# How to convert an html content to wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have the following html code that tried to place in my WordPress page.

html:

```
<div class="hovereffect">
       <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>phone.jpg" >
        <div class="overlay">
          <h2>Hover effect 9</h2>
          <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
       </div>
   </div>
```

At the moment everything is in the site except the image that does not show.
How can I use this code WordPress in a way that it can display the image?

Comment: And what errors are in the PHP Error log

Answer (score 1):

I think you forget to tell which place it should get the images from. And you are also forgetting a semicolon after the get_template_directory_uri();.

This is an example, but here i'm telling which folder to get the image from:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/your_image.jpg">
```

Comment: As this was the first answer that shows the semi-colon, and the rest of the path if needed, I'll mark this as useful.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that but it is not a good practice to paste this code as it is in WordPress editor,

upload this image in media and get link of that image 
Edit page, select text mode from top right corner of your editor and paste code these i.e

```
    <div class="hovereffect">
      <img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/img.png" >
      <div class="overlay">
        <h2>Hover effect 9</h2>
        <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is good practice create a template for that page and write there your code. 
Image replace with feature image
Heading with page title.
Detail with page content
link with page permalink.

Comment: If the resource is part of the theme, it's best to use the get_template_directory_uri(); If it is part of the content and can be changed by a WordPress user, then use the media uploads. An alternative is to use an options framework to allow the user to change static resources.

Comment: How do you know this has been entered in the editor...?

Answer (score 0):

Not enough reputation to leave a comment so I will leave this as an answer instead.

Assuming phone.jpg is at the root of your theme, you're forgetting the / (slash) before phone.jpg.

It should be

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/phone.jpg" >
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP won't get parsed inside a page. Just upload the image to the WordPress media library and link to it directly.